# Qt set custom drag cursor?

Tags: qt, mouse-cursor

How can I set the cursor used in Qt while performing a drag operation? I am using the `QDrag` class. The function `setCursor` takes a pixmap and has no way to specify the hotspot, nor do the docs specify that it could override the "no action" cursor.

I'm happy if I can just do an explicit cursor in `mouseMoveEvent` but I'm not sure how during a drag operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the source code it appears Qt is lame in this regards and has no mechanism to do this. For the X11 code the function `QDragManager::updateCursor` variables which contain the cursors it uses. Those are created using the `QCursor` constructor with constant hot-spot values (0,0). The `ForbiddenCursor` is completely hard-coded, thus preventing any alternation.

To set the cursor it calls `QApplication::changeOverrideCursor`. As a static function there is no way to intercept that call.

---

Even if the pixmaps are set (via setCursor) the intial drag cursor is still the default. This just appears to be a defect in QT.  *This is at `qdnd_x11.cpp:1948`, the pointer cursor is forcibly set at the start of a drag*

Thus there is no actual way to use custom cursors for the standard drag-n-drop.

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdrag.html but interface very much looks like you can do this. setHotSpot and setDragCursor?

Comment: which Qt version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.6 but it has the same interface. The hotspot is unrelated from the cursor function, it sets an offset to where the pixmap in setPixmap will be located.  I looked up the issue in the bug database and there are actually many related issues.

Comment: Maybe this is a cross platform issue, and it works on osx and windoze, but not with x11. Sag thing though. Do you have a support subscription? We bug those guys until a solution is found. You should also try the qt-interest mailinglist, perhaps someone is able to help you there.